# Batch conversion PDF to txt Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to convert a folder called '2017' which is filled with 63 pdfs of Supreme Court transcripts. I need them to be txt files so I can perform text analysis on them.

I saw questions about pdf to txt in R on here, but not for python. So far I've tried:

[image: converting pdf to txt like this]

However, it is not saving converted files to a new folder on my computer titled 2017-txt like I am trying to. I have created this folder on my desktop already titled 2017-txt.

Any advice? It's just printing a list of pdf names.

Answer (score 0):

The print function does not output a file. It looks like the rows you have commented out are supposed to be doing the file-writing. Try removing the # symbol at the start of those lines and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the error: CalledProcessError: Command 'pdftotext -layout 2017/15-1204.pdf 2017-txt/15-1204.pdf.txt' returned non-zero exit status 127.

Comment: Did you write this yourself? Please be aware that there are numerous available resources for Python if you google "python pdf to text". Have you tried any of those?

Comment: I saw there's python help for batch conversion that uses pdfminer but I thought pdftotxt would be the simplest.

Comment: I've been working with PDF miner and Python3 and have the issue now that "module can not be found." Have you run into this with PDF miner?

Comment: I can't say I have, I'm sorry.